# returning and counting the distinct (possibly repeated) elements of a vector

Tags: r, unique

Starting from a vector like this:

```
vec <- c(1,1,1,2,2,7,2,2,2,1)
```

I need to return all the distinct and possibly repeated elements of the vector. In the example I would like to obtain `1, 2, 7, 2, 1`.
Unfortunately `-unique-` would return `1, 2, 7`, which is not what I need.

I also need to get another vector containing, for each element of `vec`, the number of its elements repetitions. In the example it would be `3, 2, 1, 3, 1`.

Any suggetion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?rle` (Run Length Encoding):

```
R> rle(vec)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 3 2 1 3 1
  values : num [1:5] 1 2 7 2 1
```

Comment: FWIW there's an `rle` in Matlab as well.