# how to get single elements in a vector with repeated observations

Tags: r, string, vector

I am trying to get single non-consequently repeated observation from a vector in R, let's put as an example:
`v <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1)`
what I need is basically a function that gives this output
`c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1)`
I thought of a for loop for doing this, that should be something like:

```
uniq_v <- v[1]
for(i in c(1:length(v)-1)[c(1:length(v)-1) >0]){
     if (v[i]!=v[i+1]){
    uniq_v <- c(uniq_v, v[i+1])
}
 }
```

I am pretty sure that there is a better, simpler way, but I cannot figure it out.
Thank you,
Giuseppe

Comment: `rle(v)$values` would aid here, and you'll find it generally useful going forward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [returning and counting the distinct (possibly repeated) elements of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847839/returning-and-counting-the-distinct-possibly-repeated-elements-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (using dplyr):

```
v[v!=lead(v)] %>% head(-1)
```

Edit:
I realise my answer was not correct. I thought we want to ignore the last value as it doesn't change anymore, but if we want to include it, I think the easiest way is to set a default value in the lead function that's not `NA` and creates a mismatch

```
> v[v!=lead(v, default = Inf)]
[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Comment: When I run this I get `1 2 1 2 1 2 ` and not `1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ` as requested. Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: I edited my answer. Is there a better choice than `Inf` for a default value that doesn't throw errors but will create a mismatch?

Comment: That works. Thanks for updating it. - I am not aware of another solution. I find it interesting, though. I wouldn't have thought of that. Great one!

Answer (score 1):

```r
v <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1)
```

These two solutions are equivalent. They have the problem that they ignore the last digit.

```r
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, verbose=FALSE, mask.ok=TRUE)
v[v != lead(v)] %>% head(-1)
#> [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2

v[v != v[c(2:length(v), NA)]] |> head(-1)
#> [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

The reason is because the last comparison is `1 != NA` which returns `NA` when we’d need `TRUE`.
If we change it to this it works:

```r
v[!mapply(identical, v, lead(v))]
#> [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1

v[!mapply(identical, v, v[c(2:length(v), NA)])]
#> [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

The easiest solution is `rle(v)$values` suggested by @Chris. While the solutions above are
somewhat self-explanatory, the advantage of this solution is speed.

```r
rle(v)$values
#> [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

If speed is crucial there may even be a better solution:

```r
v[diff(c(v, Inf)) != 0]
#> [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Here the comparison:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  v[!mapply(identical, v, lead(v))],
  indexed = v[!mapply(identical, v, v[c(2:length(v), NA)])],
  v[v!=lead(v, default = Inf)],
  v[diff(c(v, Inf)) != 0],
  rle(v)$values
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                               expr  min    lq   mean median    uq  max neval
#>  v[!mapply(identical, v, lead(v))] 62.3 64.85 66.307  66.20 67.65 73.3   100
#>                            indexed 36.7 38.20 39.920  39.65 40.90 60.8   100
#>     v[v != lead(v, default = Inf)] 24.4 26.95 28.619  28.30 29.10 74.3   100
#>            v[diff(c(v, Inf)) != 0]  4.2  5.20  6.330   6.20  6.95 24.3   100
#>                      rle(v)$values 10.8 13.00 15.029  15.05 16.30 30.8   100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I edit my answer to include the final value. Using the default argument in `lead` is more elegant anyway I think. I think using `lead ` has the advantage that it is a direct solution that shows what is actually happening.